# Zabbix server config в Docker

Tags: docker, config, zabbix

Есть забикс сервер, приложения развёрнуты в докере.
Здача внести изменения конфиг(zabbix_server.conf).
Копирую этот файл на хостовую машину, вношу изменения, копирую файл назад.
Перезапускаю контейнер, но конфиг остаётся старый.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?